# Pasring And Formatting API Return

Tags: powershell, api

I am attempting to get the folder id, name and path.  What i end up with is one attribute for the id that has multiple entries and one attribute for the path that has multiple entries.  Here is what I have so far, really focusing on that last variable for the output.

```
   function Get-Token ($adminUserName, $adminPassword, $adminDomain, $api){
    try
    {
        $creds = @{
           username = $adminUserName
           password = $adminPassword
           domain = $adminDomain
           grant_type = "password"
       }

        $token = ""
        #echo "----------------"
        #echo "--Authenticate--"
        #echo "----------------"
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod "$uri/oauth2/token" -Method Post -Body $creds -ContentType "application/json"

        if($response -and $response.access_token)
        {
           # echo ""
           # echo "---------------------------------"
           # echo "--Authenticatication Successful--"
           # echo "---------------------------------"
           # echo ""
            $token = $response.access_token;
            return $token;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: Failed to authenticate."
            return
        }
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException]
    {
        Write-Host "----- Exception -----"
        Write-Host  $_.Exception
        Write-Host  $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
        Write-Host  $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
        $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
        $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
        $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
        $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd()

        Write-Host $responseBody
    }
}

Write-Host "Start"
$adminUsername = 'myusername'
$adminPassword = 'mypassword'
$adminDomain = $null
$uri = "https://someplacewithanapi"

$api = "$uri/api/v1"

$token = Get-Token -adminUserName $adminUsername -adminPassword $adminPassword -api $api
Write-Host "Token is"
Write-Host $token
Write-Host "Get token end"

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")

### DEFINE TLS1.2
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$response = Invoke-RestMethod $api/folders -Method GET -Headers $headers
$response |Select-Object @{L='id';E={$_.records.id}}, @{L='path';E={$_.records.folderpath}} |Select-Object id, path -ExpandProperty path
```

My output on that looks like this

```
    id                  path
--                  ----
{12, 20, 11, 10...} {\APPLICATIONS\WINDOWS\CENTRIX, \APPLICATIONS\LINUX\OLB\DOCKER, \APPLICATIONS\WINDOWS\OLB\HOSTDATA, \APPLICATIONS\LINUX...}
```

I am trying to get the output to look like this

```
id   Path
12 \Applications
20 \Applications\Linux
```

Comment: If you just do `$response.records` does it give you the desired output?

Comment: It gives a little too much, it gives the name, id, etc...and a bunch of other fields that i do not want, i guess i could just export to csv on just the $response.records then remove all the fields I do not want

Comment: So you'll want `$response.records |Select id,@{Name='Path';Expression='folderpath'}`

Comment: Yes, exactly what Mr Mathias said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, you can take advantage of powershell's implicit unrolling of the items in `$response`

```
$response.records |Select id,@{Name='Path';Expression='folderpath'}
```

Note that the expression doesn't have the `{}` or `$_` - Mathias had explained previously that if you're not actually doing anything special and you just want to rename a property you can use this syntax.

You could also handle the collection explicitly yourself with a loop such as this.

```
foreach($record in $response.records)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID   = $record.id
        Path = $record.folderpath
    }
}
```